# Obtaining properties from LDAP server (Distinguished Name, etc)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ldap

I need help with **retrieving all possible properties(Distinguished Name , etc) and values from a LDAP server** using **C# 4.0** code.
**My end user is simply going to enter the name of the LDAP server in my application.**

The LDAP server can be a private server or an open LDAP server as available in this page [Public LDAP servers](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Public%20LDAP%20Servers).
I am using `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection` class to connect to the LDAP servers and `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest` class to retrieve the values.

**Here's my problem :**

The `System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchRequest` class requires the **distinguished name** of the server as a parameter to retrieve users, group etc.
**My end-user will simply be entering the server name.**
**I have to get the distinguished name from the server via my C# code. I am unable to find(even google out) a C# solution for my problem.**
I found an application online that actually does what I wanted.
I simply provided LDAP server name and it retrieved the values(distinguished name, port no, etc) from that server.

**Could someone please provide me a solution to get the values using C# .NET 4.0.**

I cannot use any paid third party softwares or dlls.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP does not use *properties*, it has *attributes*. To fetch attributes from a server, an LDAP client must connect to the server, authenticate the connection using the BIND request, and then transmit a search request to the server and interpret the server's response. A search request consists of the following at a minimum:

- base object
- search scope
- search filter
- list of attributes to retrieve

Properly coded LDAP clients will include a size limit and time limit in addition to the above required elements.

The search result from the server will contain an integer result code, and a list of objects that matched the search request parameters (filtered by the search filter). A search can be successful but return no entries.

If the base object is not known, transmit a search request for the `namingContexts` attribute in the root DSE. The root DSE can only be obtained by using a base object of "" and a search scope of 'base'. The filter should be `(&)` or `(objectClass=*)`. The directory server publishes certain information, including the namingContexts, in the root DSE, although that information is subject to access controls like everything else.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Search Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming Best Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)
- [LDAP: The Root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but User will not provide "base object", he will just provide name of the LDAP Server on the form. I have to find out "base object" from LDAP server name (dynamically).

Comment: Search the root DSE. See [LDAP: The Root DSE](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/the-root-dse.html). The `namingContexts` attribute.